Tikz standalone: Infinite compilation when combining nodes and background
The following MWE compiles infinitely when I combine a background and a trivial node (which I plan to position using the at argument and the positioning library, and which should at some point includegraphics some pngs at the proper position). Why?
I am using TeXmaker as IDE with MiKTeX distribution updated to the latest updates. As a Compiler, I am using Xelatex (xelatex %.tex) because I plan to use the fontspec package for custom fonts.
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[background rectangle/.style={yellow}, show background rectangle]
\node(ne)[]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Thanks!

I get an error when trying to compile your code. However, wouldn't it be easier to use \pagecolor{yellow}?

Welcome to TeX.SX!

You're missing the library (anyway, it does not loops here, just errors out).
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[background rectangle/.style={fill=yellow}, show background rectangle]
\node(ne)[]{A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

works as it should:

BTW (Off topic): it works with xelatex too, but... are you sure you do not want lualatex? If it's a font problem, and you do not need some very specific xelatex function, lualatex is much more actively developed, more stable, and more powerful.

Thanks, the library addition solved it. Using lualatex works fine for me, will do!
However, what still puzzles me is why in my setup an infinite compilation loop is triggered when both you and @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz report getting errors. Would you mind sharing your setup? An error is way more useful than a freezing IDE.

I use the extension vimtex of vim editor, on Linux, which uses latexnk under the hood, and stops on every error... chances are that in some configuration of TeXmaker there is a stop on error or continue on error option, which is set to continue...
